# How to quickly connect 2 PC together using Ethernet without router / DNS

Tags: windows, networking, p2p, remote-debugging

In the field I often need to perform remote debugging on a target PC using my Delphi development IDE running on my (host) laptop. Because I cannot use any pre-existing network address infrastructure I use a cross-over network cable directly linking the two PC's. I then setup manual IP address of (say) 100.100.100.1 and 100.100.100.2 for the two and after much rebooting and fiddling I get the shared folders that I need. Finally after working in this way I have to carefully put things back to how they were.

This is pain though. There is a lot of typing and room for error. Further, sharing can take a while before things become visible. Is there some way that I can run something (or write a script) that would ease this process in any way?

Comment: You might want to tag with your OS, as this is rather specific to each one.

Comment: not exactly programming related, suggest moving to superuser.

Comment: @Jonathan: 'Delphi' pretty much suggests 'Windows'.

Comment: @9000 Oops! Missed that phrase.

Comment: it is programming related because it's about remote debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the designated intranet IP ranges: 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x, not 100.x.x.x.

Run a DHCP server on your box. The other box will most probably be already configured to use DHCP to obtain an IP address, this is the default. Windows comes with a bundled DHCP server (at least some versions, install it as a Windows component), or you can use [a third-party one](http://www.google.com/search?q=win32+dhcp+server).

You need zero rebooting on either box: all modern OSes allow to change IP addresses and routing on the fly, Windows is capable of this for at least a decade. Note that you don't need to change the IP address of your box. Often the secret of fast folder access is using the IP address, like `\\192.168.1.1\share_name` because name resolution services may take long time to kick in.

If you want both the link via the cross cable and a wired Internet/LAN link, just add another network card to your box (slightly more expensive with notebooks) and have the DHCP server only work with that dedicated card, so you don't need to touch the Internet-connected interface at all.

Comment: That's interesting. Your comment "Windows comes with a bundled DHCP server (at least some versions, install it as a Windows component)" - I've looked in 'Windows Features' (I have Windows 7 Ultimate) but cant see the relevant item. Am I looking in the correct place?

Comment: [That's what](http://iyogibusiness.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!910682C6CAA91ACB!151.entry) googling brought me. I didn't try it myself, but definitely it must be somewhere inside the networking components, as a subcomponent.

Comment: IIRC, DHCP is not installed as a component, it is enabled if you share a connection on an adapter. Relevant only if there are more than one adapter.